# Characters of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, characters

From the Cayley table:

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c | c c c c }
    & (0,0) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1)\\
    \hline
   (0,0) & (0,0) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1)\\
   (0,1) & (0,1) & (0,0) & (1,1) & (1,0)\\
   (1,0) & (1,0) & (1,1) & (0,0) & (0,1)\\
   (1,1) & (1,1) & (1,0) & (0,1) & (0,0)\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

How would I construct the characters of this group, $G =\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$?

***EDIT:*** Since $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ is abelian, all characters are one-dimensional so they take on values $\pm 1$. So we have the same character table as the Klein-4 group:

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c | c c c c }
 & (0,0) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1)\\ 
\hline  
    \chi_{(0,0)} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(0,1)} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(1,0)} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(1,1)} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

If this is correct, I can put it as a solution rather than an edit however feel free to critique my attempt.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to the Klein-4 group, does this imply the character table will be the same?

Comment: Yes isomorphic groups have isomorphic character tables. Only possibly the rows and columns would be permuted if you had put the group elements and irreducible characters in a different order.

Comment: @Ben just to check, is my orderings correct?

Comment: I don’t know your definition of the Klein four group, but the character table you wrote seems to just be the character table for $Z/2\oplus Z/2$, so you don’t have to worry about an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ is abelian, all characters are one-dimensional so they take on values $\pm 1$. So we have the same character table as the Klein-4 group:

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c | c c c c }
 & (0,0) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1)\\ 
\hline  
    \chi_{(0,0)} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(0,1)} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(1,0)} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(1,1)} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}